# Best way to implement PGP company wide

Tags: pgp, gnupg

What is the best way to implement PGP/GnuPGP company wide? Go to each users workstation, create the keys, upload the public key, and move on to the next?

Comment: Have you Googled this? There is a lot of material on "enterprise PGP". Mostly about centralised key servers.

Comment: Please expand you question a bit. It is a interesting question, but for good answers we need to know more of what you want to achieve. For example you seem to want a key per workstation instead of a key per user (or per mail address). Why? Who should send encrypted messages and who should be able to read them? Do you need it for communication inside the company or to the outside? Or both?

Comment: Ideally, each user would have his/her own key pair. I would like to encrypt all internal email at rest, we have the transit part covered. Anything we send outside with data that needs to be encrypted, we use Zix for. In my head, I would create a key pair for each user, upload their public keys, and then go around and add the set of public keys to each workstation. I will google up the centralized management/in house key servers. Being a non-profit comp, we are trying to keep cost down.

Answer (score 1):

Each person should have their own key pair (obviously). Additionally you can utilize one keypair that signs all users' keys (corporate key). Users' keys should sign that corporate key and set owner trust to "full". That way all users that are signed by the corporate keys are automatically fully trusted.

You can also use [trust signatures](https://www.linuxfoundation.org/blog/pgp-web-of-trust-delegated-trust-and-keyservers/) (gpg uses `tsign` command) if you want to expose this trust information outside or want to introduce more levels of company keys (like intermediate certificates).

Comment: The OP wants to know how to implement PGP not how to use PGP.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.